# Material UI React Input broken after upgrading to 4.0.0

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

After upgrading from `"@material-ui/core": "3.9.2",` to `"@material-ui/core": "^4.0.0-rc.0",` I get some css issues.

Example with Input, some css: `height: auto !important;` seems to be missing:

[image]

My config is the same as here: https://material-ui.com/getting-started/installation/

My code is very basic:

```
          <FormControl>
            <InputLabel htmlFor="email">{`Your email address`}</InputLabel>
            <Input
              id="email"
              onChange={e => this.setState({ email: e.target.value })}
              type="text"
              onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress}
              value={this.state.email}
            />
          </FormControl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`import 'tachyons'` was in conflict.
After removing it, it works well.